# How to prompt the message when I didn't select?

Tags: css, validation, input

when I didn't set the product size, it will show the text "Must pick 1 size for the product". But it can't show the text. I want to know how to use select and input Element?

```
<select name="product_size" class="form-control" required oninput="setCustomValidity('')"
oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Must pick 1 size for the product')">
    <option disabled selected>Select a Size</option>
    <option>Small</option>
    <option>Medium</option>
    <option>Large</option>
</select>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lJUI.jpg)

Comment: Post the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

There are a two things wrong with your code.

1. The `oninvalid` callback was never able to be executed, as nothing ever checked for the validity of the `select` element. You can fix this by wrapping it in a `form` element and have a `<button>` in it. When this button gets clicked by a user, the form gets validated by the browser, will see, that the select is invalid and call your `oninvalid` code.
2. It is never invalid in chrome. I have tested your code and it worked perfectly on Firefox after wrapping it with a form. Chrome however does not think your default option is `invalid` to make it think this I added the `value=""` attribute to it.

A working example:

```html
<form action="javascript:void()">

  <select 
    required 
    name="product_size"
    class="form-control"
    oninput="setCustomValidity('')"
    oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Must pick 1 size for the product')"
  >
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Size</option>
      <option>Small</option>
      <option>Medium</option>
      <option>Large</option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem is NO2. I add the value=" ", it works in Chrome. @Max